# MongoError: document constructed by $facet is 104860008 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am getting memory size limit error while running multiple sub-pipelines in $facet. Can someone help me on this issue.
Scenario: I have a crown job which runs once a day. I want to execute  multiple pipelines using $facet against a collection with millions of documents whenever job is triggered.

```
[ 
     {
          $facet: {
                  query1: [pipeline_1],
                  query2: [pipeline_2],
                  query3: [pipeline_3]
                  ...
                  query_n: [pipeline_n]
          },
     },
     {
        $merge:{ into: some_collection}
     }
]
```

I tried `db.collection.aggregate([], {allowDiskUse: true});`, But still  getting same error.
What can be the work around on this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases using `allowDiskUse` should eliminate this error this is why i'm suspecting you're using the wrong syntax for it. Depending on your Mongo version there are some [hard limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/) on certain operators like `$graphLookup`, these operators will always have a memory error regardless of the `allowDiskUse` flag usage.

Assuming you don't use any of these operators `allowDiskUse` will work, here is a syntax example for the `nodejs` driver:

```
db.collection.aggregate([], {allowDiskUse: true});
```

If you are `$graphLookup` or one of the other limited operators then there's not much you can do. I would start by splitting these `$facet` stages into separate pipelines. If the problem still persists you'll need to either optimize the aggregation or find a different approach.

Comment: I am using same syntax as above. It should give allowDiskUse Error/Warning but it giving memory limit error with $facet. It is working well while i used it with $group.
Is there any other way by which i can run multiple pipelines in parallel and merge output in another collection.

Comment: It's hard to answer you're question because I can't see the actual query, but under the assumption you're using the `nodejs` mongo driver (not `mongoose` or something else) and are using the syntax i gave then there's no alternative other than to just split it into different pipelines.

Comment: Hi Tom,  I am using pymongo python package to run pipeline like this: 
```db_client.aggregate(
db_name, collection_name, pipeline, allow_disk_use=True)``` It is working in case of ```$group``` but not working in case of ```$facet```.

Comment: It should be `allowDiskUse=True` I'm not sure how `allow_disk_use=True` not throwing you an error.

Comment: PyMongo is a python package, so ```allow_disk_use=True``` is absolutely fine. I checked with mongodb CLI ```db.collection_name.aggregate( [pipeline], {allowDiskUse: true}}```. still getting same error.